# Failed Export pdf from laravel webpage because execution time exceeded

Tags: laravel, pdf, timeout, export

I'm using Barryvdh\DomPDF export data from laravel webpage into pdf. But I'm getting 'Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded' [image: picture of error]

in app.php I already set Barryvdh class and aliases as PDF

in web.php

```
Route::get('/Student/Materi/singleMateri/exportPdf/{id}', 'StudentController@exportPdf')->middleware('role:Student');
```

in StudentController.php

```
public function exportPdf($id)
{
    $singleMateri = Materi::findOrFail($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadview('pages.student.materi.exportPdf', compact('singleMateri') );

    return $pdf->download('materi.pdf');
}
```

in exportPdf.blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ $singleMateri->judul }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h5>{{ $singleMateri->judul }}</h5>
            <h6>{{ $singleMateri->mapel }}</h6>
            <h6>{{ $singleMateri->kelas }}</h6>
        </center>

        <h1>{{ $singleMateri->judul }}</h1>
        <br>
        {!! $singleMateri->isi !!}
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2><strong>Kesimpulan :</strong></h2>
        <p>{{ $singleMateri->kesimpulan}}</p>
        <br>
        <h4><strong>Info :</strong></h4>
        <p><strong>Mata Pelajaran :</strong>  {{ $singleMateri->mapel }}</p>
        <p><strong>Untuk Kelas :</strong>  {{ $singleMateri->kelas }}</p>
        <br>
        <h4><strong>Keterangan :</strong></h4>
        <p>{{ $singleMateri->keterangan }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to increase max execution time? or did anyone having a suggestion how to solve this? A sure way to export data from laravel webpage to pdf?

Comment: You can increase the max_execution time in your php.ini, but I would find out why your script is taking so long.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering too why take so long